# wait for end of requestFullScreen

Tags: javascript, fullscreen, wait

I'm looking for something for a couple days but I didn't succeed yet. 
I've got a JS function call when I press button. 
This function is used for set a part of webpage in fullscreen with HMTL5.

```
function fullScreenCustom(element, tab) {
    var pere = element.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;

    if (pere.requestFullscreen) {
        pere.requestFullscreen();
    }
    else if (pere.msRequestFullscreen) {
        pere.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
    else if (pere.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        pere.mozRequestFullScreen();
    }
    else if (pere.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        pere.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else {
        console.log("Fullscreen API is not supported");
        return; 
    }

    getElementByClass(element.parentNode, "validation").click();
}
```

Last line press an other button for redraw a chart. 
The problem is on Chrome, `click()` is call before end of fullScreen.

How can I wait for fullScreen end?

Comment: 1. You better avoid `element.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode`, most probably you could just use `document` instead.

Comment: 2. It seems like you don't need `eval()` on line 14.

Comment: Yes, I don't need eval() (rest of old test). 
I use parentNode.parentNode ... because I need to put current Article in fullScreen but not full page. It work fine, even if it's not sexy.
edit: I remove eval from code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should listen for [`fullscreenchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/fullscreenchange) event (add prefixes as necessary):

```
document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", function () {
    if (!document.fullscreenEnabled) {
        // user has quit fullscreen
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I tried it but it never go in first function.

Comment: Have you used prefixes? E.g. Chrome requires `webkitfullscreenchange` and `document.webkitFullscreenEnabled`.

Comment: Thank you, I think it's this. Do you know how I can set this for all browser ? 
And if it's possible to get current full screen element ?
edit: found for current element it's document.webkitFullscreenElement